# Embedding Compiler Options in source

Tags: cobol, zos

I am moving some COBOL code from zOS to Linux and stumbled on this code at the top of a COBOL program:

```
   CBL DATEPROC(FLAG),YEARWINDOW(-90)                               004220CB
   ID DIVISION.                                                     004220CB
   PROGRAM-ID.   AL0001.                                            004220C
```

Are those compiler options that the COBOL compiler detects, or are they instructions to some kind of third party preprocessor.

My personal guess is that it is a third party processor that deals with Y2K issues in the code.

Comment: As piet already noted this is something the original compiler processed. Depending on your new compiler (which is ???) you may have similar options there.

Comment: I am going to try to use GnuCOBOL on Linux but if that does not work then I will use MicroFocus.  I will also consider writing a preprocessor to massage the code to make it work with GnuCOBOL if I understand what to change.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With IBM's Enterprise COBOL the `CBL` statement is one of several ways to provide compiler-options.

The options in your example are a bit of a special case since IBM dropped Y2K-support and thus the [`DATEPROC`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS6SG3_4.2.0/com.ibm.entcobol.doc_4.2/PGandLR/ui/up4505.htm) and [`YEARWINDOW`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS6SG3_4.2.0/com.ibm.entcobol.doc_4.2/PGandLR/ui/up4510.htm) options when moving from version 4 to version 5. With V5 compilers they should be flagged by the compiler but should not lead to a compile-error.

Comment: I've added documentation references as I think they are useful here, hope you don't mind:;-)

Comment: @SimonSobisch : so I see you hack GnuCOBOL.  What is the equivilent of this in GnuCOBOL when someone codes PIC X(2)  DATE FORMAT YY ?